# The Molar mass of the hydrocarbon is 42.0gmol^-1. Determine its molecular formula

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

As you can see, I have answered both the part (**a**) & (**b**), but I am unsure how to answer part (**c**). I am 100% sure I answered part (**a**) right; not quite positive about part (**b**) though. I'm lost on part (**c**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you did in (**b**). What I'd do is write an equation for mass percentage of hydrogen in unknown hydrocarbon $\ce{C_xH_y}$ (you can also do it for carbon with the equal result) and find $x : y$ ratio:

$$\frac{y}{12x + y} = 0.143 \implies y = 2.00 x$$

Knowing that the empirical formula is $\ce{C_nH_{2n}}$, we can solve (**c**):

$$12n + 1 \cdot 2n = 42 \implies n = 3$$

The molecular formula of hydrocarbon is $\ce{C3H6}$.

Comment: You don't even need the empirical formula. You can't get anything else that makes sense.

Comment: @Zhe True; my intention was to try to show a common approach for solving these types of questions.